# Rendering not happening when I call setState()

Tags: javascript, react-native

In React Native, I have a list for which only one element is highlighted. When an element is clicked that becomes highlighted and everything else is unhighlighted.

In the method `selectItem` I set `this.state.highlighted`. Then, in `checkIfHighlighted`, based upon `this.state.highlighted` I pass a boolean parameter to the list items, which means they are highlighted or not.

```
   export default class MyList extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {indexHighlighted: 0};
    }

    selectItem = (i) => {
        console.log("Selected different list item: " + i);
        this.setState({indexHighlighted: i});
        console.log("this.state.indexHighlighted: " + this.state.indexHighlighted);
    }

    checkIfHighlighted(i) {
        console.log("Is " + i + "hignlighted? " + (i == this.state.indexHighlighted));
        return i == this.state.indexHighlighted;
    }

    render() {
        console.log("In render, this.state.indexHighlighted: " + this.state.indexHighlighted);
        return ( 
            <FlatList
                renderItem={ ({item}) =>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.selectItem(item["indexNr"])}>
                        <View>
                            <MyListItem
                                key={item["indexNr"]}
                                highlighted = {this.checkIfHighlighted(item["indexNr"])}
                                orderInList={item["indexNr"]} />
                        </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                }
                keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index}
            /> 
        );
    }
}
```

When I press on an item and check the logs, this line is executed in `selectItem`:

```
console.log("Selected different list item: " + i);
```

After that, the state should be set:

```
this.setState({indexHighlighted: i});
```

However, the next line in `selectItem` is not executed:

```
console.log("this.state.indexHighlighted: " + this.state.indexHighlighted);
```

Also, this line in `render()` is not executed:

```
console.log("In render, this.state.indexHighlighted: " + this.state.indexHighlighted);
```

So what is happening? Why is `render()` not called?

Since I am updating the state with `setState()`, the whole component should be re-rendered, right?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? As there are 2 logs in selectedItem, and only 1 is getting displayed, there should be an error

Comment: No errors. But the component is not re-rendered.

Comment: The component will render if the state is updated. But in either case, you should also get second log. If you are not getting that, put a debugger and debug for errors

Comment: May be try removing arrow function. You are binding context twice.

Comment: Does the first console.log in selectItem print the value of 'i' correctly?